# Signatures on arbitrary data

Tags: gnosis-safe

I don't think it's possible for owners of a safe to sign arbitrary data, while using the same UI for giving permissions (like queue shows txs that need permission) as when executing txs.

I am developing a safe-app in which I need the ability for owners to sign arbitrary data to approve something. After which the signatures will be relayed to a backend and perform some action.

The only way I can implement this within safe-app is by implementing the entire UI for managing signatures myself, which might be lengthy. Plus having two different flows (1) for approving transactions (2) for approving arbitrary data might be confusing user experience. I was wondering whether there's any plan to support something like this? Or is there any other way I can implement this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `safe-apps-sdk` there's a method for signing messages `sdk.safe.signMessage`:
https://github.com/gnosis/safe-apps-sdk/tree/master/packages/safe-apps-sdk#signing-messages

The signing happens on-chain because the Safe doesn't have a private key to sign data and is controlled by the code on the blockchain. To validate the signature, use a method defined by [EIP-1271: Standard Signature Validation Method for Contracts](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1271)

You could also get signatures from N (= threshold of the safe) safe owners, concatenate them and pass to the validation method. It is supported on the contract level but we don't support it on the UI/Infra level:
https://github.com/gnosis/safe-contracts/blob/main/contracts/handler/CompatibilityFallbackHandler.sol#L35